# Qual è il significato dell'espressione "a parola libera" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Mentre contemplava quel trombone, con il desiderio struggente di portarlo alla bocca e manovrare la coulisse – almeno un’altra volta – lesse sulla vetrina del negozio la réclame di una conferenza sulla guerra: *L’Italia in Tripolitania*. L’entrata era **a parola libera** – anzi, “essendo il tema d’attualità, pregasi i connazionali a intervenire in massa”. La pubblicità prometteva realistiche visioni della vita sul fronte del deserto.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "a parola librera" in questo brano. Me lo potreste spiegare? Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI09/GDLI_09_ocr_27.pdf&parola=parola%20libera) ho trovato che "parola libera" vuol dire una parola che termina in vocale, ma questo non sembra avere senso nel contesto del testo sopra citato.

Comment: Immagino significhi che era possibile entrare ad assistere la conferenza con la possibilità di intervenire liberamente, per esempio ponendo delle domande. In altre parole, la conferenza prevedeva il coinvolgimento del pubblico.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ritengo significhi che era possibile assistere la conferenza con la possibilità di di interagire, di intervenire liberamente, per esempio ponendo delle domande. In altre parole, la conferenza prevedeva il coinvolgimento del pubblico.

Gli organizzatori caldeggiavano un intervento *di massa* delle persone per dare appunto vita ad un dibattito.